# Vectorize Pandas DataFrame By N-Gram of Characters, and Append Column Name

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I am trying to vectorize a pandas dataframe into separate n-grams of chracters. There is a caveat though, I want the column name to be part of the character sequence. For example, let's pretend this is the raw data:

```
First Name, Last Name
John, Smith
```

and I am using character n-grams of length 3.

I want the following n-grams to be generated:

```
"First Name_Joh", 
"First Name_ohn", 
"Last Name_Smi", 
"Last Name_mit", 
"Last Name_ith"
```

so I can create a one-hot-encoding for that vector. I want the column name to be part of the character n-gram sequence. For what I am working on, I don't want all the n-grams to be lumped together. (Sorry if I'm not using the correct terms; I'm not good with explaining this material.)

^ I know how to this this with loops, in an inefficient way; however I need this to be scalable and reusable, so I want to use something like sklearn's CountVectorizer to do this. How can I do this?

Comment: Loops are really your only choice here. Note, `CountVectorizer` *uses loops*

Comment: You could try converting the strings to some numbers and operating on them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is exactly what you want, but perhaps you can use `CountVectorizer` with a character analyzer, and iterate over the columns to gram.

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

data = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'first_name': ['John', 'Ed'],
        'last_name': ['Smith', 'Bean']
    }
)

vec = CountVectorizer(analyzer = 'char', ngram_range = (3, 3))

output = pd.DataFrame()

for i in data.columns:

    pre = pd.DataFrame(vec.fit_transform(data[i]).toarray(), columns = [i + '_' + j for j in vec.get_feature_names()])

    output = pd.concat([output, pre], axis = 1)

pd.concat([data, output], axis = 1)
```

Gives:

[image]

Or perhaps you'd like the names as values?

```
output * output.columns
```

Gives:

[image]